# Get "ActivityID" from that specific "Activity" if I push the button

Tags: php, javascript

I'm making a button which deletes an record from a mysql database.

I have made a database with 3 tables, 1: user, 2: activity, 3:user_activity. 
In the user_activity you can find the UserID (from user) and ActivityID (from activity).

I have alreade made a script that can add both UserID and ActivityID to the user_activity table. But now i also want a button that remove that "row".

so i made this javascript code with an onclick function:

```
$(".deleteActivity").click( function() {

    var user_activityId = $(this).data('activity');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_activity.php",
        data: {
            activity: user_activityId
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {          
        }
    });
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

And I made this delete_activity.php file:

```
<?php
  include "connection.php";

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."' ";
  $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stm->execute(array());
  while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $userID = $row['UserID'];
  echo $userID;
}

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE UserID = '".$userID."' ";
  $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stm->execute(array());
  while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['ActivityID'];
}
?>
```

And this is the button:

```
echo '<input type="button" class="deleteActivity"  value="Activiteit verwijderen" data-activity="' . $row['ActivityID'] . '">';
```

As you can see, don't delete anything yet, i only "echo" the ID's so I can see the ID's and check if those are the right ones.

I want to get the ActivityID from the "activity" on which I puch the button. With this ActivityID an can finish my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE UserID = '".$userID."' AND ActivityID = ??? ";
```

I hope everything is clear and that there is someone that can help me.

Comment: Use the `bindValue` instead of concat your query string manually. However, `var_dump` your `$userId` to make sure that it has data.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'm new in PDO so I appreciate the tips. But unfortunately, it will not solve my problem. Is there a way you can help me with that?

Comment: Can you show me the result of `var_dump($userId)`? Modify your code a bit to show up the SQL error if it exist (insert before your execute statement): `if ($stm->execute()) {var_dump($stm->fetchAll());} else {var_dump(stm->errorInfo());}` can you show me the result, too?

Comment: It shows no errors, it gets all the data it needs. But the problem is that if I push 1 button, I collect all of the ActivityID's where the UserID = $userID. And I want to collect that specefic ActivityID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your posted user_activity_id on your query :D I don't know the column name of your `user_activity_id`, so edit it in your case.

```
$userActivityId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "activity");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_activity WHERE UserActivityId = :id";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue( ":id", $userActivityId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($stm->execute())
{
    $rows = $stm->fetchAll();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
         echo $row['ActivityId'];
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a user_activityID. the only rows in my user_activity are ActivityID and UserID. So i have changed "UserActivityId" to ActivityID. But i have no output, it says: array (size=0) empty...

Comment: So what do you post from ajax, `user_activityId` contains which information?

Comment: I don't use ajax for that (I know it is a better way, but I use this query:
$sql =  "SELECT activity.*"."FROM user_activity, activity "."WHERE user_activity.ActivityID = activity.ActivityID AND user_activity.UserID = '".$userid."' " ;

Comment: Allright, I have found the problem, in my JS I referred to the table " user_activity" instead of "activity".